# Ubuntu 19.04 randomly boots to GRUB command line

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 19.04

I am running a dual boot with Windows 10 on one M.2 SSD and Ubuntu 19.04 on another M.2 SSD (both Intel SSDs, different sizes).

I have set my boot order to boot the Ubuntu SSD as highest priority because I want to have a way of choosing what I'll boot (i.e. the usual GRUB choice to boot Ubuntu or boot using Windows boot manager) and I have GRUB installed on the Ubuntu SSD. This is typically what I get, however, on occasion (I'd estimate about 1/3 of the time) I get the GRUB command line, where I have to type "exit" before I am greeted with the usual GRUB interface and can choose my OS as usual.

This is made even stranged b the fact that if I manually select a boot drive (by pressing F7 with my BIOS) I am never given the command line, always the usual GRUB display.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated, because, while it does no real harm, it's just really annoying!

Comment: What happens if you type `exit` in the grub command line is, that your BIOS will jump to the next entry in the boot order list. I assume you've chosen the wrong boot entry to be used first. Most probably this is a result from installing Ubuntu in the wrong boot-mode (UEFI vs legacy) and a succesfull attempt to repair the boot, but an obsolete boot-loader still exist.

Comment: mook765 when I type exit I am greeted with the normal grub screen where I can choose between Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Windows Bootloader and entering setup.

Comment: I didn't say anything else, please reread my comment carefully and try to understand.

Comment: @mook765 my apologies, I misread.

Comment: I have the exact same issue between a dual boot ubuntu and windows 10. About 1/3 of the time I get the grub prompt which after typing exit gets me to the correct grub menu. There are 3 hard drives in the system. I think a failed ubuntu install of 22.10 caused this.

Comment: Edit: For me this appears to be solved by adding a 5 second bootup delay in the bios